# remove apostrophe from json returned sql data + codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I have the below field in my database query:

```
REPLACE(ProductCode,concat((width*1000),(thickness*1000),REPLACE((convert(varchar,convert(decimal(8,1),length))),'.','')),'') as grade,
```

this is then returned to the view from codeigniters model and controller:

**Model:**

```
function get_skugrade_grade($q)
{
    $Query="select
              min(grade) as family
            from (SELECT
                    REPLACE(ProductCode,concat((width*1000),(thickness*1000),REPLACE((convert(varchar,convert(decimal(8,1),length))),'.','')),'') as grade,                     
                  FROM database.dbo.ProductList) as p
            where Options like '%$q%'";
    $result = $this->db->query($Query)->row();
    return $result->family;
}
```

**Controller**

```
function get_skufamily_grades(){
    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
        $q = strtolower($_POST['data']);
        $viewData   =   $this->Sales_model->get_skugrade_grade($q);
        $data_json = json_encode($viewData);
        echo $data_json;
    }
}
```

**View request:**

```
$.post('get_skufamily_grades', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) 
 { 
 $('input[name^="skugrade_1"]').val(result);
 });
```

The output to the view is `"CR"`. How can I remove the two apostrophe's `""`

the database result simply has `CR`. I think my jquery / json is addint these in as it is not a number being returned.

current server response

[image]
Thanks as always.

Comment: the `""` is added by json encoding

Comment: can you share your ajax request also

Comment: Thanks Arun, added to question as per your request.

Comment: what is the value returned from `get_skufamily_grades` is it a simple string or an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `""` is added by json encoding, valid json format is `{ "key" : "value" }` where the key and values are enclosed within `"` for values other than `Number` and `Boolean`.

If you configure your ajax request to handle json request you can solve this problem, with `dataType: "json"`

Update
I'm not a PHP guy, still tryy something like

```
function get_skufamily_grades(){
    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
        $q = strtolower($_POST['data']);
        $viewData   =   $this->Sales_model->get_skugrade_grade($q);

        $arr = array('family' => $viewData);
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
}
```

Then change the ajax request to

```
$.post('get_skufamily_grades', {
    data : selectedObj.value
}, function(result) {
    $('input[name^="skugrade_1"]').val(result.family);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: thanks Arun, appreciated. my ajax request / vview request is added to the question. can you calrify with my syntax? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Arun, still comes through with the "". I edited the question to show the server response

Comment: `$.post('get_skufamily_grades', {data : selectedObj.value}, function(result) {
      result = result.replace('"', ''); 
      result = result.replace('"', ''); 
    $('input[name^="skugrade_1"]').val(result);}, 'text');` does the trick but I don't think it is optimal?

Comment: @Smudger no it is not, you need to fix root cause

Comment: @Smudger try the update, check the response string also using browser developer toolbar

Comment: response is still `"EX"` so bringing the apostrophes with. Thanks.

Comment: the response should be `{ "family" : "Ex" }`, is it?

Comment: Sorry Arun, apologies. this does work perfectly. I didn't update the controller. 100% now. response is just `EX` as desired.

Comment: @Smudger now we are using json data instead of text

Comment: Awesome. perfect, thank you Arun. I'll need to fully understand this still. appreciate your time!